# Button appending duplicate data to div on successive click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with class "data-section" and a button with class "get-first-data". On click, the button should populate the "data-section" div with data extracted from a get request. However, I want the content of the "data-section" div to first be deleted before making the get request to prevent duplicates on successive click events.

I wrote the below code for that and i am experiencing this issue;

1. The extracted data from the get request are being appended to the "data-section" div without first removing existing content. Hence, I have duplicates on multiple button clicks --- Any idea why and suggestion on how to fix?

```js
    $(function() {
      $(".get-first-data").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".data-section").empty();
        
        $.get("/get-first-data", function(data, status) {
          $(".data-section").html(data)

          
          $.get("/get-second-data", function(data, status) {

            
            data.forEach(function(element) {

              var name = element.name;
              var age = element.age;

              $('table tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + name +
                '</td><td>' + age +
                '</td><td><a class="edit-data btn btn-dark">Edit</a></td></tr>')
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

```
Below is the html code
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="get-first-data" type="button" name="button"></button>

  <div class="data-section">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please add your html

Comment: also add mock API https://designer.mocky.io/ using this tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns out to be very simple; Replace `$(".get-first-data").on("click", function(e)` with `$(".get-first-data").unbind().on("click", function(e)`

The unbind method ensures that the click event is only sent once by first removing handlers from the button before listening for events on every clicks. Hence, successive clicks doesn't result into duplicates as `$(".data-section").empty();` is able to clear the div effectively

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me where the data returned by the "/get-second-data" call is being placed, but i will assume it is placed in the same "data-section" as the /get-first-data"
call. If that's the case then try placing $(".data-section").empty(); after the "/get-second-data" call as well like so:

```js
    $(function() {
      $(".get-first-data").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".data-section").empty();
        
        $.get("/get-first-data", function(data, status) {
          $(".data-section").html(data)

          
          $.get("/get-second-data", function(data, status) {
            //Add this here
            $(".data-section").empty();
            data.forEach(function(element) {

              var name = element.name;
              var age = element.age;

              $('table tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + name +
                '</td><td>' + age +
                '</td><td><a class="edit-data btn btn-dark">Edit</a></td></tr>')
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: The data returned by the get request to /get-first-data is just filling the "data-section"  with html code for a table with pre-filled header information but empty tbody. Second get request to /get-second-data returns user data which are appended to the aforementioned table as tr.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but i am still getting duplicates on successive click event on the button. Almost like as if the "data-section" div was never emptied out to begin with